# search by username function in my flutter application using firebase returns a Future<dynamic> instance

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, chat

i have a chatting application and i want to do a search function where the user can enter into a textfield another users username and to show the searched users username and name so the user can message them,

the problem i have is that when i retrieved from my firebase the user with the same username entered it returned a `Future<dynamic>` instance which then results in an error in using docs: "`The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Future<dynamic>'` "

here is my code

```
class _search extends State<search> {
  TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();
  late Future<dynamic> searchResult;
  bool haveUserSearched =false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("search for user"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Color(0xfffffefa),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  // GestureDetector(
                  //   onTap: (){
                  //     print(getUserByUsername(searchController.text));
                  //   },
                  //   child: 
                    Expanded(child: TextField(
                    controller: searchController,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffBFBBB7)),
                    onSubmitted: (value){
                      print(getUserByUsername(searchController.text));
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "search by username",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffBFBBB7)),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Color(0xffBFBBB7),),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ),
                  //),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    
  }

  //-------methods and widgets-------
  getUserByUsername(String username) async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('name',isEqualTo: username).get();
  }

  Widget userTile(String name,String username){
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                name,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                username,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              //sendMessage(userName);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12,vertical: 8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)
              ),
              child: Text("Message",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16
                ),),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget userList(){
    return haveUserSearched ? ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 1, ///?
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return userTile(
          searchResult.docs[index].data['name'], //the error here is in docs "The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Future<dynamic>' "
          searchResult.docs[index].data["username"],
        );
        }) : Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`searchResult` is a `Future`, a representation of an eventual result (or error) from an asynchronous operation. You need to wait for the result, which you can do in various ways, such as `await` or [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). In this circumstance, you may opt to choose the latter.

Please see [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Use futureBuilder inside Column and pass fetched data like `Widget userList(users) {`

It can be like

```dart
class _search extends State<search> {
  TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

  bool haveUserSearched = false;
  late Future<dynamic> searchResult = getUserByUsername(searchController.text);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("search for user"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Color(0xfffffefa),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: searchController,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffBFBBB7)),
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                        searchResult = getUserByUsername(searchController.text);
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "search by username",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffBFBBB7)),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Color(0xffBFBBB7),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: searchResult,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return userList(snapshot.data);
                }

                return Text("handle other state");
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //-------methods and widgets-------
  getUserByUsername(String username) async {
    final result  = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('name', isEqualTo: username)
        .get();
   User myUser  = User(name: result['name'] .....)  //get user from Map.. it cant be..
   return myUser;  
  }

  Widget userTile(String name, String username) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                name,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              ),
              Text(
                username,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              //sendMessage(userName);
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
              child: Text(
                "Message",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget userList(user) {
    return haveUserSearched
        ?  userTile(
                user.name,
                user.username,
              )
        : Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it resulted in an error:  `Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'.`

Comment: then i tried changing  `FutureBuilder` to `FutureBuilder <User>` but it showed an error saying `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<User>'`

Comment: are you trying to fetch userList?  also you need to convert to model class from snapshot data

Comment: its suppose to fetch only one user.  what does it mean converting to model class? and how can i do it? (I'm sorry I'm new to flutter) @Yeasin-Sheikh

Comment: It depends on console data structure & snapshot. try to check [get data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)